# Bulk convert csv files in Google drive to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I'm trying to select a few csv files that are in my Google drive and convert them to Google Sheets files. I know that I can do this one by one using the Open option, but since I have hundreds of files, I'm looking for a way to do this using multi-select and convert.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know two ways to convert multiple files, and "multi-select and convert" is not one of them.

#### Reupload

Download the files, then upload again, having first enabled "convert uploads" in Drive settings.

#### Script

Using an [Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/), one can convert CSV files to Google Spreadsheet format automatically. First, move the files to be converted to a folder and take a note of its id (the part of the shareable link after `?id=`). Use the folder id in the following script.

```
function convert() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folder id here');
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Drive.Files.copy({}, file.getId(), {convert: true});
  }
}
```

Follow the instructions to enable [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive), which is used by the script. Finally, run it. It will create converted copies of all files in the given folder.

Comment: Awesome @Bookend. The script worked like a charm! Just to add a bit to the scenario, my files are copied to Google Drive automatically and updated by a script for 24 hours, hence I couldn't use the convert=true at the time of uploading.

Comment: BTW, Would you have any pointers on copying files to another folder and running this script at midnight automatically? Thanks again for your prompt and concise response.

Comment: Use a [timed trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) to run a function every 24 hours. For simply copying files there's [makeCopy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopydestination) in the standard [DriveApp service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app). But if you know which files are to be converted, then you don't need to move them to a folder; just loop through the files and convert. One option is to `DriveApp.search` to locate the files.